# High disk load after wake up from sleep mode of Windows 7 without restart

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sleep

I have hp elitebook 840 g3 T9X24EA. The Disk drive light is lit for about 5 minutes after wake up from sleep mode of Windows 7. The login field does not appear for about 5 minutes. A restart resolves the problem immediately, but then the problem reappears slowly with time and reaches the 5 minutes in about 10 days. In 10 days after a restart, the login field appears in 5 minutes after wake up from the sleep mode.

My 3 other slower computers with different Windows 7 versions resume from sleep mode even longer. It looks like, the longer Windows 7 is not restarted the longer it resumes from the sleep mode. How to prevent this problem?

Comment: It’s probably Windows updates - it checks periodically and can be resource intensive of Win 7. If you don’t have enough RAM and/or too many programs open when you sleep you’re going to experience delays. But I wouldn’t think the login screen would take 5 minutes. But it’s almost certainly a not enough RAM issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Should selecting "nether check for updates..." and unchecking the options for automatic updates help?

Comment: Can MSE load HDD when PC is returning from the sleep or the hibernation?